# Is there correct/better way to cross html into php and vice versa

Tags: php

I sometimes download sample code like everyone else does to save time and not have to reinvent wheels

I just came across this after a pretty complex code function so the person who wrote it seems to know what they're doing PHP wise:

```
<?php if (isset($menu)) { ?>
    <?php echo $menu; ?>
  <?php } ?>
```

Why would you not instead write:

```
<?php if (isset($menu)) { echo $menu; } ?>
```

Curious as to which is better and if so why?

Comment: It's just a style question, I would consider neither good style, but both are valid. If there's no HTML involved, don't break out of PHP. You should still indent your PHP properly, I frown upon one-line `if` statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your first example, there is no need to close and then re-open the PHP tags, it can be done just as you provided in example 2.

```
<?php
    if(isset($menu)){
        echo $menu;
    }
?>
```

The only reason you would need to close and then re open the tags is if you wish to print out some more HTML as well:

```
<?php
    if(isset($menu)){ ?>
        <div id="menu">
            <?= $menu ?>
        </div>
    <? }
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

This is purely a matter of taste / style, it has no impact on functionality or even on the design of the system. Just like the alternative syntax doesn't impact anything in any way, other than style. That could have been very well written as:

```
<?php if (isset($menu)): echo $menu; endif ?>
```

and it would've been the same thing.

Do however note that for pure logic files, it's often a bad idea to break out of PHP. The code below:

```
<?php if ($test == 1) { ?>
    <?php ++$test; ?>
<?php } ?>
```

is similar to:

```
<?php

if ($test == 1) {
    echo "    ";
    ++$test;
}
```

which introduces the unwanted and often overlooked side effect of printing four spaces (or a tab, or whatever you used for indenting the `<?php ++$test; ?>` block). The same thing applies for the closing `?>` - it's often better to leave it out in pure logic files, since editors tend to add an empty newline character at the end of the file, which, if it follows a `?>`, will be `echo`ed.

Answer (score 0):

To me it's all a matter of preference and what I'm trying to achieve..

In a 100% PHP code file I might do this:

```
if (isset($somevariable))
{
    // do some stuff here
}
```

or even this

```
if (isset($somevariable)) echo htmlentities(print_r($somevariable, true));
```

Whereas in a mixed HTML / PHP file (such as a view) I may do this:

```
<table>
<?php foreach ($result_set as $row) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td><?php echo $row['column']; ?></td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

Which I find much easier to distinguish

I have no opinion which is "better"

Answer (score 0):

there is no functional difference between the two snipplets.

The code might have looked initially like this:

```
<?php if (isset($menu)) { ?>
<a href='home.php'>Home</a> | <a href='links.php'>Links</a>
<?php } ?>
```

And just the second Line has been adapted to by generated dynamically.

Comment: Why did they have the `$menu` variable then?

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can see for this is if there is HTML mixed in with this code such as

```
<?php if (isset($menu)) { ?>
    Html stuff here
<?php echo $menu; ?>
    More html stuff here.
<?php } ?>
```

I can not imagine any practical purpose for this however.

I personally would do something like your example 2.  There is no reason to break from PHP.

Answer (score 0):

If you have PHP shorttags enabled you could use

```
<?=$menu ?>
```

which means exactly the same as the folowing line:

```
<?php echo $menu;?>
```

And for your if case this might be usefull, but might be less clear

```
<?=isset($menu)? $menu : "" ?>
```

and if you are looking to combine the lines remember that newlines are allowed:

```
<?php
    if(isset($menu)){
        echo $menu;
    }
?>
```

You might also want to Google PHP template libraries if you don't like messing with code.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought rather than a question, but I can't post code in comments so here goes.

Maybe it's just a legacy formatting?
I.e. previously it was something like:

```
<?php if (isset($menu)) { ?>
    <p>Here comes the menu!</p>
    <?php echo $menu; ?>
    <p>So how did you like it?</p>
<?php } ?>
```

Then someone else removed the HTML and left the PHP untouched.

Anyways, I agree with @Matt Clark (even before he edited his answer:)) and @rid and the others that the code should be easily readable and formatted according to the industry standards.